# Lost in Authentication - what kind of JWT authentication is this?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Somehow I solved my actual problem but I am somehow dissatisfied because I don't fully understand. I don't even have enough words to seach for.

I am working on integrating Only office with authentication tokens.

The callback (to save the document) is a HTTP-POST with some JSON payload in the body:

```
{  
    "key": "00020000010000009675",
    "status": 1,
    "users": [
      "2"
    ]
  }
```

Once security (shared secret) is enabled, the office editor also sends an Authentication HTTP-header with *Bearer* scheme (or what nomenclature that is). A JWT.

Decoded the JWT resembles the Payload as already in the body (POST):

```
{
  "payload": {
    "key": "00020000010000009675",
    "status": 1,
    "users": [
      "2"
    ]
  },
  "iat": 1576857169,
  "exp": 1576857469
  }
```

Header of the HTTP request about circa in ASP.Net mvc:

`HeaderAuthorization = {Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwYXl...`

**Question:** What kind of authentication is this? Has it a name to search for?

And how to verify this? The JWT is a simple shared secret thingy. So checking the Token as such is ok. But if my code reads only from the body and the middle ware checks only the Token..... will that be an *authentic* solution?

**BTW**
In case my (found) solution is of interest, I provide some details here:

I have security set up already but in that special case of the call back I need special treatment (another security scheme). So I set up my controller as so:

```cs
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "OnlyOfficeBearerToken")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> OnlyOfficeCallbackHandler()
        {
            // Claim Payload aus dem verschlüsselten Token auslesen, wenn es geht.
            Claim payloadclaim = this.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "payload");
            string body = payloadclaim?.Value;
```

body contains my authenticated message payload. As said: the same as in the actual body. But I don't know if this solution ensures both are the same - I guess NO. So one may just pretend to take that claim's content.

On the other hand I had to extend the filtering of that ASP.Net core app in the setup like so in the startup:

```cs
                var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["OnlyOffice:CallBackSecret"]));
                services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer("OnlyOfficeBearerToken",
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            ValidateAudience = false,
                            ValidateActor = false,
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey =
                                securityKey //new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);,
                        };
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        options.SaveToken = true;
                        // Extra-Handler:
                        //options.SecurityTokenValidators.Insert(0, new BodyChecker());
                    });
```

you see the string `OnlyOfficeBearerToken` on both sides that is how it connects.

So my question persists: What is the name of that protocol?

Comment: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: all well found as 1st hit. But it does nowhere explain if there exists a standard to use the body of an HTTP-POST and put it into the payload of a JWT in an Authorize Header with Bearer token. That concept is what I am curious about. PLUS Does it verify the body is trustworthy - probably not or does my ASP framework check this already?

Comment: There's nothing specific about a Bearer JWT as an auth scheme.  Most don't provision for also validating the body (like some HMAC schemes do) but that's something you could easily do as well or in addition to.  Depending on how you are getting the JWT token to send (are you crafting it, or is it being returned from some other authentication endpoint?) you could use the JWT or have an additional scheme for signing payload attributes.

Comment: "Bearer Authentication" is a general term for passing a token; using a JWT as that token is one such flavor but there are other ways of doing so.